# Applications of Finite Automata in Computer Science

Tags: computer-science, automata

I have to choose a topic from applications of Finite Automata for my presentation.
What are some applications of Finite Automata in Computer Science? They might be in programming.

Comment: See also [here](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8539/how-practical-is-automata-theory).

Comment: This question would have been perfect for the upcoming [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science-non-programming?referrer=pdx8p7tVWqozXN85c5ibxQ2). So, if you like to have a place for questions like this one, please go ahead and help this proposal to take off!

Answer (score 2):

[Lexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexing), [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing), [scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29), networking (e.g. [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) & [routing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing)), [event-driven programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) ... use finite state automata.

Actually, automata are used everywhere in computer science & in programming. It might be harder to name programming techniques which don't even remotely use them.

But your question belongs more to [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) than to here.

Answer (score 0):

A finite automata is highly useful for designing Lexical Analyzers, as it can be applied to many different types of data. Text editors can be designed with a finite automata. Spell checkers can be designed using a finite automata. Transducer is a tool for designing sequential circuits (a finite automata).
1.A finite automata (FA) is a method for designing a compiler’s lexical analysis.
2.Automata Push Down (PDA) – For designing the parsing phase of a compiler (Syntax Analysis)
3.Genetic programming can be implemented using linear Bounded Automata (LBA).
4.The Turing Machine (TM) – a machine that can read minds.

Answer (score 0):

The automata method enables computer scientists to understand how machines compute functions and solve problems, as well as what it means for a function to be defined as computable or for a question to be described as decidable.

Applications:
1.For the designing of lexical analysis of a compiler.
2.For recognizing the pattern using regular expressions.
3.For the designing of the combination and sequential circuits using Mealy and Moore Machines.
4.Used in text editors.
5.For the implementation of spell checkers.

Finite Automata(FA) is the simplest machine to recognize patterns. The finite automata or finite state machine is an abstract machine that has five elements or tuples. It has a set of states and rules for moving from one state to another but it depends upon the applied input symbol.

Finite automata can be represented by input tape and finite control. Input tape: It is a linear tape having some number of cells. Each input symbol is placed in each cell. Finite control: The finite control decides the next state on receiving particular input from input tape.